# Protoc generated base file name differs for java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

When I compile protocol buffers for Java output, the generated base file name differs from that of the proto file used. For C++ and Python, the base file name of the generated files contains the base name of the proto file, as expected.

**Example** 
Let's have a basic proto file `abc_v6.proto` in dir `proto` with minimal contents:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package dummy.pkg;

message ImportantMessage {
    optional uint32 code = 1;
};
```

Now, if we compile protocol buffers for c++, java and python using:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/ --cpp_out=. proto/abc_v6.proto
protoc --proto_path=proto/ --java_out=. proto/abc_v6.proto
protoc --proto_path=proto/ --python_out=. proto/abc_v6.proto
```

- generated c++ files: `abc_v6.pb.cc  abc_v6.pb.h`
- generated python file: `abc_v6_pb2.py`
- generated java file: `dummy/pkg/AbcV6.java`

For python and c++ the part of name `abc_v6` remains intact in the generated file names.
However, for java, the generated java file is `AbcV6.java` for protofile `abc_v6.proto`.

---

- Why is the file name for generated Java file different?
- What are the underlying rules that govern the altered names for generated Java files for a given proto file name? (I need it for an automated build script in the scope of a larger project)

Comment: I don't know if there's a technical reason but certainly the name 'abc_v6' is unidiomatic for a Java class (and by extension a Java file) though it would compile.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- would you also happen to know naming guideline for protoc from proto to Java? (Similar to the independent Java naming convention you shared above)

Comment: You'd probably need to look at the implementation in protoc; note that for Java the  `java_multiple_files`, will generate one file per message. But the larger point stands that each language's implementation in `protoc` is free to adopt whatever convention they want. Most do their best to generate the most idiomatic convention possible, which for Java means using UpperCamelCase names.